# For + Loop functions combined in R

Tags: r

I think the way to do it in R is quite simple but I cannot get the result I want.
Basically, I am trying to compare two vectors of values (i.e., y and z) row by row such that if y>z, I get "A" and in case y<z then it gives me "B".
Here is what I did, but it does not seem to yield anything:

```
y <- Insider_Outsider_10days$return_10days

z <- Insider_Outsider_10days$Return_Outsider_10days

Insider_Outsider_10days$`Insider-Outsider` <- for(i in 1:nrow(Insider_Outsider_10days)){
  
if (y>z) {

      Insider_Outsider_10days$`Insider-Outsider`<- ("A")

} else {

  Insider_Outsider_10days$`Insider-Outsider`<- ("B")

     }

}
```

I would be really thankful if you guys could me on that!!

Comment: By y > z you mean y - z is positive for all pairs of vector elements?

Comment: Study `help("ifelse")`. You don't need a loop.

Comment: FYI use backticks  not single quotes to format code on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SteveM, y and z can be either positive or negative

Comment: @Roland, thank you very much! I believe this is the simplest solution by far

Answer (score 0):

Note that you could also simply collect the comparisons as logical values. E.g.:

```
set.seed(7)
y <- sample(1:10)
z <- sample(1:10)
Insider_Outsider_10days$Insider-Outsider <- y > z
Insider_Outsider_10days$Insider-Outsider
 [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```